# How to add internal user to one of the rules in Check Point's Mobile Access blade

Tags: checkpoint

I want to add an **internal user** to one of the rules in Check Point's Mobile Access blade.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Access rules doesn't allow adding individual user, only as part of Internal User Group. Therefore, you have two steps here:

1. Add Internal User Group

   - In `SmartDashboard`, click the `Users and Administrators` tab (also accessible from **File** -> **Manage** -> **Users and Administrators**).
   - Right click **User Groups**, and select **New Group**.
   - Fill **name** and, optionally, other fields.
   - Click **OK**.
2. Add Internal User

   - In `SmartDashboard`, click the `Users and Administrators` tab (also accessible from **File** -> **Manage** -> **Users and Administrators**).
   - Right click **Users**, select **New User** and then select **Default**.
   - In `General Properties` tab fill **User Name** and, optionally, other fields.
   - In `Groups` tab, select the newly added group (in step 1) from **Available Groups** and add it to **Belongs to Groups**.
   - Click **OK**.

Now you're ready to add Internal User Group to Mobile Access rule. To do that:

- In `SmartDashboard`, click the **Mobile Access** tab.
- Find your rule, right click over its **Users** column, and select **Add
  Users**.
- In drop-down, select **Internal User Groups**.
- Double click on your group name to add it.
- Save changes.
- Install policy.